# Can't detect sound card (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

My soundcard has suddenly stopped working after a reboot. No audio devices appear on sound settings and alsa doesnt detect my soundcard. I've tried to follow some guides I found on the Internet but it hasn't worked. On Windows I have no problem.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=c0d6ce239768ff35f671d77b391b32ad843b0663

Here you can see more information about my problem (I suppose it may be useful, I'm new to linux and didn't need to solve things like this before...)